# I made a JText Field in netbeans and i let the user to input his data by getting text. i Want to check weather the the text field is empty or not?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield

```
if(age.getText().equals("")==true||name.getText().equals("")==true||ssn.getText().equals("")==true||cv.getText().equals("")==true||position.getText().equals("")==true||phone.getText().equals("")==true
    ||city.getText().equals("")==true|| HouseNo.getText().equals("")==true||street.getText().equals("")==true||mail.getText().equals("")==true|| nationality.getText().equals("")==true
    ||zip.getText().equals("")==true)) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please Enter your info again");
    Apply.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Please put a little effort into your question.

Comment: Don't compare boolean entities with `true`. You can just eliminate `==true` everywhere in that code snippet.

Comment: `JTextField#getText()#trim#isEmpty`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.isBlank, which does the following: Checks if a String is **whitespace, empty ("") or null**.You wont need to explicitly call the trim() method either,as it checks for whitespace also.This class is available in apache-commons-lang.jar

```
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(age.getText())||StringUtils.isBlank(name.getText())||
    StringUtils.isBlank(ssn.getText())||StringUtils.isBlank(cv.getText())||StringUtils.isBlank(position.getText())||
    StringUtils.isBlank(phone.getText())||StringUtils.isBlank(city.getText())|| StringUtils.isBlank(HouseNo.getText())||StringUtils.isBlank(street.getText())
||StringUtils.isBlank(mail.getText())||StringUtils.isBlank(nationality.getText())||StringUtils.isBlank(zip.getText())) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please Enter your info again");
            Apply.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this while checking on the recently added questions. The most common and simplest way to do this is to use `getText()` `isEmpty()` and `trim()` methods.

`yourJTextfield.getText().trim().isEmpty();` // this will return true if empty and false if it isn't.

The reason we used trim() is to remove any leading or trailing spaces in case the user pressed space while typing a String.

I hope this helps.